# Logstash - can an alert be setup based on a filter

Tags: logstash

With logstash releasing version 1.2.1, there is an email output now.

in the specs for it, it states that it will send an email when any event is recieved [doc](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/outputs/email)
is there a away to use grok to state that if the message contains 'some bad event' that it will send an email as well as send to elastic search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found an example in the older version. [example](http://drewsearcy.com/email-alerts-with-logstash/)
With the match feature deprecated, just swap out using the conditional processing. [link](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/configuration#conditionals)